# Compress text horizontally to fix a given width

Tags: tables, width, scaling

I'd like to make a table with each cell having a given width, and with the text in each cell being compressed to fit that width, as in:

[image]

which I achieved manually using:

```tex
\begin{table*}
\begin{center}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
  \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
  \hline
  \scalebox{.9}[1.0]{AAA}
  & BBB
  & \scalebox{.75}[1.0]{CCCC}
  & \scalebox{.65}[1.0]{DEFGH}
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

I managed to do the following with `adjustbox`'s `\maxsizebox`:

[image]

```tex
\begin{table*}
\begin{center}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
  \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
  \hline
  \maxsizebox{2em}{!}{AAA}
  & \maxsizebox{2em}{!}{BBB}
  & \maxsizebox{2em}{!}{CCCC}
  & \maxsizebox{2em}{!}{DEFGH}
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

However, I would like only horizontal compression, not vertical one.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `graphicx` package and running `\resizebox{3em}{\height}{AAA}`, `\resizebox{3em}{\height}{BBB}`, etc?

Comment: Is the cell width to be specified, or is it set to the minimum natural width, as in your example?  If the former, do you want cells whose natural width is below the specified width to be stretched?

Comment: Not to pick on any one, but IMO, this doesn't seem a good idea at all, the compressed cells look "ugly" to me.

Comment: @Mico it almost work as it compresses text that is too long, but it also stretches text when it is smaller than the cell, which is not what I want.

Comment: @AboAmmar My use case is that I have a lot of columns with short name abbreviations in the headers. But some of these abbreviations have a few more letters, and I don't want the corresponding columns to appear larger. I want every column to have exactly the same width. The maximum compression I get for those abbreviations with more letters is minor, so it does not look too jarring.